Powershell returns some random values from a function
I wrote a function that should return an object or $null. What the code does instead, is it's returning an array which contains $policyTxtBlock (input param), and then either the object or null.
Why does is behave so weird? Why doesn't it respect the return keyword?
class PolicyEntry {
    # Class properties
    [string]   $Type
    [string]   $Path
    [string]   $Key
    [string]   $Value
}

Function Parse-PolicyEntry([string]$policyTxtBlock) {
    Write-Output $policyTxtBlock
    $lines = $policyTxtBlock.Split("\n")
    $policyEntry = [PolicyEntry]::new()
    $valid = $false

    #...some logic...

    if ($valid) {
        return $policyEntry
    } else {
        return $null
    }
}


A common question.  A function returns all output.  The return keyword isn't usually needed.

At least one duplicate here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663848/powershell-function-doesnt-have-proper-return-value. In short, capture any return values from methods and functions called inside your function (the write-output $policyTxtBlock in your sample, but also possibly something in the … some logic …) otherwise they get implicitly written to the output stream from your function up to the caller. Options are $null = …, [void] … and … | out-null to swallow / capture unwanted return values...

In short: any output - be it from a PowerShell command, an operator-based expression, or a .NET method call - that is neither captured in a variable nor redirected (sent to a file or via the pipeline to another command) is implicitly output from a script or function. To simply discard such output, use $null = ....
If you don't discard such output, it becomes part of a script or function's "return value" (stream of output objects), which is not limited to what is passed to an - optional - return statement.
See the linked duplicate for more information.

Specifically, in your case it is the Write-Output $policyTxtBlock command that contributes to the function's output too. If your intent is to print status / verbose / debugging information, you can use Write-Host /  Write-Verbose / Write-Debug without polluting the success output stream, but note that the latter two require opt-in to produce visible output.

Thanks everyone, your answers have helped me! I'm not sure who designed such behavior, but I hope they didn't get to design much more - this behavior is ridiculous.

. As for the design rationale: PowerShell is a shell first, and, like other shells (e.g. Bash), its commands (including functions and scripts) are organized around streams rather than return values (except for class methods); similarly, commands are invoked like shell commands, i.e. without parentheses around the list of arguments, and with arguments separated with spaces.
This takes some getting used to if you come from a dedicated programming language such as C#, but the streaming nature of PowerShell  is a
powerful concept, especially when used in a pipeline.
