# Why does this method return two values?

Tags: string, function, powershell

This method should take in a string, and return `true` if it is all zeros or `false` if there is at least one other character in the string:

```
Function check0ID($fixedString) {

    foreach ($char in $fixedString) {
        If ($char -ne "0") {
            $false
        }
    }

    $true

}
```

This method will return:

`false
true`

even when the string is not all zeros. Why doesn't this method stop after returning `$false`? NB If you want to give a more efficient method with the same functionality, please do :)

Comment: What's even stranger is I just commented out the `$true` at the end, and it still gives me the same output?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things here:

1. You need to explicitly use the [`return` keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847760.aspx) to exit a function prematurely.  For more information, see [Function return value in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286164/powershell-function-return-value).
2. You need to call the [`System.String.ToCharArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c7h58e5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on `$fixedString` so that it is treated as an array of characters.  Otherwise, `$char` will be equal to `$fixedString` within the loop body.  You can see this for yourself by adding the following line just under the loop header:

   ```powershell
   Write-Host "`$char equals $char"
   ```

Below is a fixed version of your script:

```powershell
Function check0ID($fixedString) {

    foreach ($char in $fixedString.ToCharArray()) {
        If ($char -ne "0") {
            return $false
        }
    }

    $true

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're making this way too complicated. Instead of doing all the micro-management of iterating over all characters in a string, you could simply do a regexp match and return the result:

```
function ContainsNonZero($fixedString) {
  [bool]($fixedString -match '[^0]')
}
```

Comment: This is faster than the method described in the other answer but I accepted @iCodez because he explained why what I was doing wasn't working...I still up voted your answer, though! Thanks!