# Passing down a variable to function creates an array

Tags: powershell

I have already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478715/how-to-define-the-return-type-outputtype-of-a-function) about Powershell return values in Powershell, but I can simply no wrap my head around why the following `New-FolderFromName` is returning an array - I expected one value(a path or a string) in return:

[image]

```
$ProjectName="TestProject"
function New-FolderFromPath($FolderPath){
    if($FolderPath){
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $FolderPath)) {
            Write-Host "creating a new folder $FolderName..." -ForegroundColor Green
            New-Item -Path $FolderPath -ItemType Directory
        }else{
            Write-Host "Folder $FolderName already exist..." -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
}

function New-FolderFromName($FolderName){
    if($FolderName){
        $CurrentFolder=Get-Location
        $NewFolder=Join-Path $CurrentFolder -ChildPath $FolderName
        New-FolderFromPath($NewFolder)
        return $NewFolder
    }
}

$ProjectPath=New-FolderFromName($ProjectName)
Write-Host $ProjectPath
```

Also tried to add the following to `New-FolderFromPath` as this function seems to be the problem or altering the parameter:

```
[OutputType([string])]
param(
    [string]$FolderPath
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens as a Powershell function will return everything on the pipeline instead of what's just specified with `return`.

Consider

```
function New-FolderFromName($FolderName){
    if($FolderName){
        $CurrentFolder=Get-Location
        $NewFolder=Join-Path $CurrentFolder -ChildPath $FolderName
        $ret = New-FolderFromPath($NewFolder)
        write-host "`$ret: $ret"
        return $NewFolder
    }
}

#output
PS C:\temp> New-FolderFromName 'foobar'
creating a new folder foobar...
$ret: C:\temp\foobar
C:\temp\foobar
```

See, the `New-FolderFromPath` returned a value which originates from `New-Item`. The easiest way to get rid of extra return values is to pipe `New-Item` to null like so,

```
New-Item -Path $FolderPath -ItemType Directory |out-null
```

See also [another a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24548723/503046) about the behaviour.