# Why does PowerShell return a new line?

Tags: powershell, whitespace

I've recently broken into some of the subtler nuances of PowerShell, and noticed something I cannot avoid involving the return of a new line at the start of a string using this mundane function...

```
Function Why() {
    ""
    return "Well I tried."
}
```

This returns "\r\nWell I tried".

```
Write-Host "Starting test."
$theBigQuestion= Why
Write-Host $theBigQuestion
Write-Host "Ending test."
```

This will output the following:

```
Starting test.

Well I tried.
 Well I tried.
Ending test.
```

Now, this appears PowerShell is concatenating one output with another. But... why? What makes it think that I wanted the blank line to be part of the return statement? I (perhaps erroneously) like to use lines like this as shorthand, or to examine variables more closely for debugging purposes.

Related: [Function return value in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286164/powershell-function-return-value)

Comment: what is the `""` doing in the function? that is what echoing the blank line `\r\n`

Comment: @bansi `""` was originally echoing a blank line to the console. It's a bad habit of mine. I know the "what", but I'm trying to figure out the "why".

Comment: Which version of powershell is this? I do not see a blank line or "Well I tried." printed twice in 4.0.

Comment: @mikez This is PowerShell 2.0... which may be causing the problem.

Comment: `get-help about_return`. Anything that is not captured in a function will get returned. use write-host and you won't have this problem

Comment: I tried this on version 2.0 as well. I see the same output as 4.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function:

```
Function Why() {
    ""
    return "Well I tried."
}
```

Is returning an array of two strings.  The first string is an empty string and the second is "Well I tried.".  When PowerShell displays an array of string it puts each string on a newline.

```
25> $r = why
26> $r.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

27> $r[0].Length
0

28> $r[1]
Well I tried.
```

Comment: ...and here I was thinking it was returning a string the entire time. Derp.... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have *"Well I tried"* to return, you can also use [Out-Null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null?view=powershell-6) or assign the unwanted return value to `$null`

```
Function Why() {
    Out-Null ""
    return "Well I tried."
}
```

or

```
Function Why() {
    $null = ""
    return "Well I tried."
}
```

or

```
Function Why() {
    "" > $null
    return "Well I tried."
}
```