# Powershell Need To Specify Type Of Object

Tags: powershell

Why do I need to declare the type of a variable when assigning it with a list?

In the below code, I need to specify that `$firstList` is of type `list[string]`, if I don't do that, then its type is `Object[]`, even though in the function returning that list, the list is of type `list[string]`.

```
function StartProgram
{
    [system.collections.generic.list[string]]$firstList = getList
    $secondList = getList
    Write-Host "firstList is of type $($firstList.gettype())"
    Write-Host "secondList is of type $($secondList.gettype())"
}

function getList
{
    $list = new-object system.collections.generic.list[string]
    $list.Add("foo")
    $list.Add("bar")
    return $list 
}

StartProgram
<#
    Output:
    firstList is of type System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
    secondList is of type System.Object[]
#>
```

Comment: Its the return keyword that is throwing you. Check out [this]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286164/powershell-function-return-value). If you check the type of `$list` before the return you will find its the correct object type

Comment: I took out the return keyword, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell functions write output to the output stream and when a collection is presented as output, the default behavior is to enumerate the collection and output that.  What you get on the other side - when you assign the output to a collection - as an array of objects.  That is, the List gets lost during the output operation.  You can change this behavior by wrapping the list in an array with it as the single element by changing the return statement to;

```
return ,$list
```

or more simply just;

```
,$list
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify an attribute on the function to prevent this "auto-enumeration" feature and simply return the object as-is?

Comment: No but there may be a feature coming in V5 that will allow you to create a method in a class. Hopefully those `def` methods won't enumerate output but it is too early to say for sure (or even if the feature will even make it into final bits).