# Unable to cast object to System.Net.Sockets.Socket

Tags: .net, sockets, powershell, types

I'm trying to retain the .NET type when creating a TCP client in powershell. I have the following code:

```
function New-TcpClient() {
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$true)]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $RemoteHost,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Int32]
    $Port
)

Write-Output "Creating a TCP connection to '$RemoteHost' ..."
$TcpClient = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($RemoteHost, $Port)
if ($TcpClient.Connected) {
    Write-Output "A connection to '$RemoteHost' on port '$Port' was successful."
} else {
    throw "A connection could not be made to '$RemoteHost' on port '$Port'."
}

return $TcpClient.Client
}
```

I'm pretty sure the type of $TcpClient.Client should be System.Net.Sockets.Socket, but what if I try to use this function and set the return value to a variable, I get the type System.Object[]. If I try to cast the object like the following:

```
[System.Net.Sockets.Socket]$client = New-TcpClient -RemoteHost "myhost" -Port "23"
```

Then, I get the exception that Powershell cannot convert the type System.Object[] to System.Net.Sockets.Socket. How should I go about retaining the actual type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the lines that have `Write-Output`. Be default function return *all* output. That would mean you text as well. This can be verified from running this command

```
(new-tcpclient -RemoteHost thing.server.com -Port 1234)[0]
Creating a TCP connection to 'thing.server.com' ...
```

That is why it is returning `System.Object[]` and the cast is failing. Change those lines to `Write-Host`

```
...
Write-Host "Creating a TCP connection to '$RemoteHost' ..."
$TcpClient = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($RemoteHost, $Port)
if ($TcpClient.Connected) {
    Write-Host  "A connection to '$RemoteHost' on port '$Port' was successful."
...
```

And PowerShell will handle the rest like it always does.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> (new-tcpclient -RemoteHost thing.server.com -Port 1234).GetType().FullName
Creating a TCP connection to 'thing.server.com' ...
A connection to 'thing.server.com' on port '1234' was successful.
System.Net.Sockets.Socket
```

Top it off with some supplementary reading: [Function return value in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286164/powershell-function-return-value)

Comment: Thanks! That seems to fix it