# PowerShell function

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this PowerShell version 2 function ...

```
function Get-Sids{
    #[CmdletBinding()]
    param ([string]$all_sids)

    $all_sids | foreach-object { $_.Substring(20) }
    return $all_sids
}
```

The substring method is removing the first 20 characterss of the string like I want it to. The problem is it is only doing it on the first element of the array.

Example input

```
$all_sids = "000000000000000000testONE", "000000000000000000testTwo", "000000000000000000testThree"
```

output

```
stONE 000000000000000000testTwo 000000000000000000testThree
```

I shouldn't need to move to the next element in the array, right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly called the parameter a single `String`. You need to set it as an array like so:

```
function Get-Sids{
    #[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # Note the extra set of braces to denote array
        [string[]]$all_sids
    )

    # Powershell implicitly "returns" anything left on the stack
    # See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286164/powershell-function-return-value
    $all_sids | foreach-object { $_.Substring(20) }
}
```

Comment: That was it! I had to do the same to my variable, as well, because I was set as a single string value.  Thanks @Eris

Comment: I realized the `return` was incorrect, so I updated the answer.