# PowerShell: Querying AD attribute "unexpected token in expression or statement

Tags: string, powershell, active-directory

I recently had to change my powershell script to query a SIP address in a different attribute in AD.  But I'm not sure how to write it so I can query the "msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress" in Active Directory.  This is due to the '-' in the msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress attribute.  When I hover my mouse over the squiggly line, it says "unexpected token in expression or statement"

I can query other things from AD suchs as name, mailnickname etc.   But I need this one specifically because of the way we are changing our SIP address.

```
Function CheckSIP {

    $loggedOnUser = (get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "Name='explorer.exe'"|Select -First 1).GetOwner().User

    $strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(mailnickname=$loggedOnUser))"
    $objDomain = New-Object 

    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Offices,dc=OurNetwork,dc=net")
    $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
    $objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
    $objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
    $objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"

    $colProplist = "name", "mail", "mailnickname", "msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress"
    foreach ($i in $colPropList){$null = $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}

    $colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

    foreach ($objResult in $colResults){

        $objItem = $objResult.Properties
        [string]$UserName = $objItem.name 
        [string]$mail = $objItem.mail
        [string]$mailnickname = $objItem.mailnickname
        [string]$sipaddress = $objItem.msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress
    }

    $theSIP = $sipaddress.Split("@")[0]    
    return $theSIP
}

$mySIPaddress = CheckSip
```

I'm aware of the "Get-ADUser" command, but not all of our machines will have this commandlet natively on their machine.  So that is why I'm doing it like this.

Comment: That prop msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress is not in your `$colProplist`?

Answer (score 1):

Remember, the hyphen is an operator.  Try:

```
[string]$sipaddress = $objItem.'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress'
```

---

You also need to specify the property for the searcher:

```
$colProplist = "name", "mail", "mailnickname","msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress";
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange($colProplist);
```

I eliminated the unnecessary loop as well.

Comment: I've tried that already and it does not return anything.  I know the attribute I'm testing does have a value because I'm looking in AD directly.  I just need the script to return that value.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the unnecessary loop.   You are correct, it's not needed when getting one thing.  Actually, I don't need the "mail", "mailnickname" or "name".  I just needed the msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress.  

I killed the foreach loop and did what you said it and it's better.  But I'm still not getting any data returned.

Is there something wrong that I'm missing?

Comment: Hi BaconBits. This is still not returning anything.

Comment: @TheInfamousOne  I'm not sure.  You can load all properties by not loading any properties at all.  Test that with a user to see what properties you get back.

Comment: okay, I just found out it's case sensitive.  I changed the attribute from this "msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress" to this "msrtcsip-primaryuseraddress"  It's spelled exactly the same, but all lower case. I guess PowerShell did not like the upper case.   Problem solved and thanks for the pointers.

Just an FYI, I will pulling the msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress attribute from Active Directory directly.  when I kicked out the $objItem, I noticed it was all lower case and tried it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Going by BaconBits suggestion and getting rid of the loop.  Here is what the working function looks like.

```
Function CheckSIP {
$loggedOnUser = (get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "Name='explorer.exe'"|Select -First 1).GetOwner().User
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(mailnickname=$loggedOnUser))"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Offices,dc=ourdomain,dc=net")
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$colProplist = "name", "mail", "mailnickname", "msrtcsip-primaryuseraddress";
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange($colProplist);

    $colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
    $objItem = $colResults.Properties
    [string]$sipaddress = $objItem.'msrtcsip-primaryuseraddress'
    $theSIP = $sipaddress.Split("@")[0]
    $theSIP2 = $theSIP.Split(":")[-1] 
    return $theSIP2
    }
```

As you can see, I changed it to all lower case for msrtcsip-primaryuseraddress and it worked.

Thanks BaconBits!