# Can't return object from powershell module function

Tags: powershell, module, scope, powershell-3.0

OK, I looked, and read, then looked some more... For the life of my I cannot figure out why my object will not return from my function! This is contained in a module within a separate file being called from another script. Everything is assigned properly BUT once this function loses scope so do the variables... How do I return the wiStore object OR set it so it does not lose scope after words.

Edit: Please note that nothing is returned, I can see the variable set in the debugger but magically it goes null after the function has finished executing.

```
function Get-WiStore
{
    param
    (
        $CollectionUrl
    )

    Add-TfsReferences
    $tfsUri = New-Object System.Uri $CollectionUrl
    $tfProjectCollection = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection $tfsUri
    #WHY DO YOU DISAPEAR!!!!?!?!?!?!?!?!?! :'(
    $wiStore = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore $tfProjectCollection
}



function Add-TfsReferences
{
    #my *.dll references       
}
```

Comment: `($wiStore = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore $tfProjectCollection)`

Comment: after you set `$wiStore`, place it on a line on its own before the last brace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function return value in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286164/function-return-value-in-powershell)

Comment: Hrmm, still doesn't answer on how to return that singular object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue myself, the problem was my references were failing but power shell failed to notify me. If you require references for a module then you should create a Module Manifest. Also, I removed the variable $wiStore and simply returned a new object.

```
function Get-WiStore
{
    param
    (
        $CollectionUrl
    )

    $tfsUri = New-Object System.Uri $CollectionUrl
    $tfProjectCollection = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection $tfsUri
    New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore $tfProjectCollection
}
```

Please see an answer to my other question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38246932/3812871

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to return $wiStore there are two ways you can do it.  The first would be to just call it at the end of your function, the second would be to use the [RETURN keyword](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847760.aspx) to explicitly tell powershell to return the value.

```
return $wistore
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was due to the references failing to add correctly. Please see my answer below.