# Add-Type in a function contained in a module

Tags: function, powershell, dll, scope

I'm not sure why this is failing, but if I Add-Type from a function then for whatever reason my code fails when I need to use the *.dll api.

```
function Add-References
{
    Add-Type -Path "C:\myDllPath.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\myDllPath2.dll"
}
```

I have tried making the function global, the dot operator... Keep in mind this function is contained in a module and is being called by a script. My goal is to just use the function to declare my references rather than copy paste these paths in all of my scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you included the error you're receving.

But I suggest an alternative: [use the `RequiredAssemblies` key in your module manifest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849709.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Specifies the assembly (.dll) files that the module requires. Enter
>   the assembly file names. Windows PowerShell loads the specified
>   assemblies before updating types or formats, importing nested modules,
>   or importing the module file that is specified in the value of the
>   RootModule key.
>
> Use this parameter to list all the assemblies that the module
>   requires. This includes assemblies that must be loaded to update any
>   formatting or type files that are listed in the FormatsToProcess or
>   TypesToProcess keys, even if those assemblies are also listed as
>   binary modules in the NestedModules key.

Comment: This is great! Thanks. I have a quick question; I have a module MyModule.psm1, do I create a Manifest with the same naming convention MyModule.psd1 OR specify MyModule.psm1 is a nested module? It's not too clear on how to use the manifest but I'm assuming I create one manifest for multiple similar modules, nest the modules in the manifest and import the manifest in my scripts.

Comment: @user3812871 the manifest has the same name but with psd1 extension (`MyModule.psd1` corresponds to `MyModule.psm1`), at least typically. The manifest specified the `RootModule` so I suppose in theory they could be named differently but I would recommend against that.