# Using FolderBrowserDialog in Powershell - returns wrong data

Tags: powershell, folderbrowserdialog

I have seen the post "How to properly use the FolderBrowserDialog in Powershell"

I am having an issue getting just the path selected to return from the function.

At the end of the script I "write-host $a" but instead of getting just the directory I selected (C:\Temp) I get 
System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 C:\Temp

Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory)

{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")

```
$foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"

if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
{
    $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
}
return $folder
```

}

$a = Get-Folder
Write-Host $a

I was told this is obsolete and to use Add-Type.  Not getting just the path with the following script.

```
   Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
   $FolderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
   [void]$FolderBrowser.ShowDialog()
   $FolderBrowser.SelectedPath
   Write-Host "FolderBrowser= "$FolderBrowser
```

Comment: You probably have `$folder` defined outside the scope of the function, and the function is modifying that. Close PowerShell and re-launch it. Also, change your `$folder +=` to just `$folder =`.

Comment: thanks!  its working with the help of you and Jon

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that result because this line also produces output:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
```

PowerShell returns all output from a function so your results are actually an array containing the output from the loading of the assembly and the folder name.

Adding [void] in front of the assembly loading operation like this will omit that extra output and give you the results you are expecting:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
```

Or as Anthony Stringer mentions in the comments, you can use Add-Type instead which does not produce any output and would probably be the preferred method:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

Also, TheMadTechnician is correct that you don't need the +=, just the = for the $folder variable.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10288256/6595659) explains the behavior of returning output from a PowerShell function in more detail.

Comment: because of this (obsolete): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12xc5368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 i recommend this: `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: OK, obsolete is not what i want.  tried Add-Type and not getting the result i need.                                                                                                                   Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FolderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
[void]$FolderBrowser.ShowDialog()
$FolderBrowser.SelectedPath
Write-Host "FolderBrowser= "$FolderBrowser

Comment: Looks like you added [void] in front of $FolderBrowser.ShowDialog(). You don't want to do that because you just basically sent the results to null. You only need to use [void] or pipe something to Out-Null when you want to discard its output.

Comment: Jon removing the void does not help.  in the original script is did replace [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")  with
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms and that worked.  Thanks rock star!