# How to use a powershell function to return the expected value?

Tags: powershell

As we know, PowerShell has wacky return semantics.

[Function return value in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286164/function-return-value-in-powershell) shows there are two main ideas to wrap my head around:

- All output is captured, and returned
- The return keyword just indicates a logical exit point

Even things like reserving variables in outer scopes cause output, like `[boolean]$isEnabled`. Another good one is `$someCollection.Add("toto")` which spits the new collection count. Even `Append()` function causes output.

For example :

```
Function MyFunc {
        $res1 = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
        $res1.Append("titi");
        $res2 = "toto"

        return $res2
}

$s = MyFunc
Write-Host $s
```

The output is : `titi toto`.

The expected output should be `toto`.

How to use a powershell function to return the expected value? (at least when viewed from a more traditional programming perspective)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When PowerShell was being developed, the team wanted to make it simple to use. But, it was confusing to people who know `return` from other languages. The implementation in classes is an attempt to rectify that mistake.

The `return` keyword works very differently in methods in PowerShell classes. It works like the `return` statements in other languages.

In a class method, the `return` keyword:

- Exits the current scope.
- Returns the associated object (return ).
- Returns only the associated object.
- The object that Return returns must match the return type of the method.

It is consistent with the `return` keyword and analogous keywords in other languages.

```
class ClassMyFunc
{
    [string] MyFunc
    {
        $res1 = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
        $res1.Append("titi")
        $res2 = "toto"

        return $res2
    }
}

$cmf = New-Object -TypeName ClassMyFunc
$cmf.MyFunc()
```

The output is : `toto`, as expected.
Using classes solved my problem, without having to search all functions returning a value in the console and piping it to `Out-Null` (as suggested by [@TobyU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10071078/tobyu)).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$res1.Append("titi");
```

to

```
$res1.Append("titi") | Out-Null
```

because the function returns every output which otherwise would be visible in the console.

Comment: Is this the only solution? It seems very tedious to do this for each function returning a value in the console.

Comment: $n = $res1.Append("titi") would work to. I'm always using Out-Null and don't no any other solution besides the two I've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

if by using 'toto' you are trying to understand if your function succeeded, you could do

```
Function MyFunc {
    $res1 = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
    $res1.Append("titi") | Out-Null
    return $?
}
```

"$?" returns a boolean if the previous command succeeded (true) or failed (false).  so externally it would look like

```
$s = MyFunc
if ($s) {
    Write-Host "successful" -Foregroundcolor Green
}
else {
    Write-Error "unsuccessful"
}
```