# Powershell function returning an array instead of string

Tags: powershell

i'm importing a csv and i would like to add a column to it (with the result based off of the previous columns)

my data looks like this

```
host address,host prefix,site
10.1.1.0,24,400-01
```

i would like to add a column called "sub site"

so I wrote this module  but the problem is, the actual ending object is an array instead of string

```
function site {
    Param($s)
    $s -match '(\d\d\d)'
     return $Matches[0]
}

$csv = import-csv $file | select-object *,@{Name='Sub Site';expression= {site $_.site}}
```

if I run the command

```
PS C:\>$csv[0]

Host Address :10.1.1.0
host prefix  :24
site         :400-01
sub site     : {True,400}
```

when it should look like

```
PS C:\>$csv[0]

Host Address :10.1.1.0
host prefix  :24
site         :400-01
sub site     : 400
```

EDIT: I found the solution but the question is now WHY.

If I change my function to `$s -match "\d\d\d" |out-null`  I get back the expected 400

Comment: The `$s -match '(\d\d\d)'` outputs True. That gets passed to the pipeline if you do not suppress it.

Comment: and fwiw - if you subsite is always 3 characters like your regex shows, following woud do without the need of an extra function `*,@{Name='Sub Site';expression= {$_.site.SubString(0,3)}}`

Comment: thanks, great idea. However my case is a bit more complicated then I actually posted so it isn't always at the front!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good you found the answer.  I was typing this up as you found it.  The reason is because the `-match` returns a value and it is added to the pipeline, which is all "returned" from the function.

For example, run this one line and see what is does:

```
"Hello" -match 'h'
```

It prints `True`.

Since I had this typed up, here is another way to phrase your question with the fix...

```
function site {
    Param($s)
    $null = $s -match '(\d\d\d)'
    $ret =  $Matches[0]

    return $ret
}

$csv = @"
host address,host prefix,site
10.1.1.1,24,400-01
10.1.1.2,24,500-02
10.1.1.3,24,600-03
"@

$data = $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv

'1 =============='
$data | ft -AutoSize

$data2 = $data | select-object *,@{Name='Sub Site';expression= {site $_.site}}

'2 =============='
$data2 | ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thanks, I also thought of another way and that's to take the last index of the array that gets returned  so `site $($_.site)[-1]`  However I think I like your solution more since you aren't guaranteed to get an array back from every function.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the most idiotic things Powershell devs have ever done. In c# the language doesn't try to override the coders desires. This is so ridiculous.

Anyway you can put the entire function inside of @() | Out-Null, like so

```
function site {
    Param($s)
    {
    $s -match '(\d\d\d)'
    } | Out-Null;
    # custom object or string or whatever here
     return $Matches[0]
}
```

Some reading
https://www.davemason.me/2021/11/29/powershell-functions-and-return-types

[Function return value in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286164/function-return-value-in-powershell)