# Powershell not returning correct value

Tags: function, powershell, return

As some background, this should take an excel file, and convert it to PDF (and place the PDF into a temporary folder).

E.g. 'C:\Users\gjacobs\Desktop\test\stock.xlsx'
becomes
'C:\Users\gjacobs\Desktop\test\pdf_merge_tmp\stock.pdf'

However, the new file path does not return correctly.

If I echo the string $export_name from within the function, I can see that it has the correct value: "C:\Users\gjacobs\Desktop\test\pdf_merge_tmp\stock.pdf".

But once $export_name is returned, it has a different (incorrect value): "C:\Users\gjacobs\Desktop\test\pdf_merge_tmp C:\Users\gjacobs\Desktop\test\pdf_merge_tmp\stock.pdf".

```
function excel_topdf{

    param(
        $file
    )
    
    #Get the parent path
    $parent = Split-Path -Path $file

    #Get the filename (no ext)
    $leaf = (Get-Item $file).Basename

    #Add them together.
    $export_name = $parent + "\pdf_merge_tmp\" + $leaf + ".pdf"

    echo ($export_name) #prints without issue.

    #Create tmp dir
    New-Item -Path $parent -Name "pdf_merge_tmp" -ItemType "Directory" -Force

    $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
    $objExcel.visible = $false

    $workbook = $objExcel.workbooks.open($file, 3)
    $workbook.Saved = $true

    $xlFixedFormat = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType” -as [type]
    $workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $export_name)
    $objExcel.Workbooks.close()
    
    $objExcel.Quit()

    return $export_name
}

$a = excel_topdf -file 'C:\Users\gjacobs\Desktop\test\stock.xlsx'
echo ($a)
```

Comment: `New-Item` returns the item it created, it gets concatenated with your return output. Assign it to a throwaway variable or otherwise discard it.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thanks a lot. Can I ask why the behaviour of new-item is to concatenate to a return?

Comment: [New-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.1#outputs) returns the object is has created.

Comment: It's not New-Item as such, anything returned by any cmdlet will be concatenated into your output, that's just how Powershell is designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is caused by the way how PowerShell returns from functions. It's not something limited to `New-Item` cmdlet. Every cmdlet which returns anything would cause function output being altered with the value from that cmdlet.

As an example, let's take function with one cmdlet, which returns an object:

```
function a {
 Get-Item -Path .
}

$outputA = a
$outputA

#### RESULT ####

    Directory:


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d--hs-       12/01/2021     10:47                C:\
```

If you want to avoid that, these are most popular options (as pointed out by [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen) in comments):

```
# Assignment to $null (or any other variable)
$null =  Get-Item -Path .

# Piping to Out-Null
Get-Item -Path . | Out-Null
```

**NOTE**: The behavior described above doesn't apply to `Write-Host`:

```
function b {
 Write-Host "bbbbbb"
}

$outputB = b
$outputB

# Nothing displayed
```

[Interesting thread to check if you want to learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10288256/9902555).