# How to declare a variable in Powershell based on a function in order to pass it as an argument in another function?

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to declare $workbook1 as the current workbook in order to pass it as an argument in another function, but it is not working. Here is my code:

Here is my code:

```
Function Open-Workbook($path, $file, $excel) {
    try {
        $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open("${path}${file}")
    }catch{
        echo $error
        $key = 'Open-Workbook';
        $date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd';
        Log-Error $key $date;
        $error.Clear()
    }
}

Function xlRefresh($wb){
    try{
    $wb.RefreshAll()
    }catch{
         echo $error
         $key = 'Run-xlRefresh';
         $date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd';
         Log-Error $key $date;
         $error.Clear()
    }
}

$paths = "C:\Users\"
$files = "Detect Scripts.xlsm" 

try{
    $setexcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $setexcel.Visible = $true
    }catch{
        echo $error
        $key = 'Open-Excel';
        $date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd';
        Log-Error $key $date;
        $error.Clear()
}


$workbook1 = Open-Workbook $paths $files $setexcel
xlRefresh $workbook1
```

When I run this, I get this error:

**You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.**

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You didn't actually output the workbook from your first function, therefore you catch nothing in your variable. Just write it out at the end.

```
Function Open-Workbook($path, $file, $excel) {
    try {
        $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open("${path}${file}")
    }catch{
        echo $error
        $key = 'Open-Workbook';
        $date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd';
        Log-Error $key $date;
        $error.Clear()
    }
    $wb
}
```

Or as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) commented, you can simply not capture it and write it implicitly

```
Function Open-Workbook($path, $file, $excel) {
    try {
        $excel.Workbooks.Open("${path}${file}")
    }catch{
        echo $error
        $key = 'Open-Workbook';
        $date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd';
        Log-Error $key $date;
        $error.Clear()
    }
}
```

Comment: ... or just omit `$wb =` altogether and let `$excel.Workbooks.Open()` pass its return value through as output of the `Open-Workbook` function.

Comment: That would also work. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually [return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-7.2) the value from the function.

e.g. `return $excel.Workbooks.Open("${path}${file}")`

Comment: While this surely works, note that in PowerShell you don't need the `return` statement in most cases. Just writing out `$excel.Workbooks.Open("${path}${file}")` on its own line would be sufficient. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10286164/7571258