# What Does this "." do in this Script?

Tags: powershell

I have two questions, both are related to a suggested answer to a question that someone else posted.
The original post is:
[stack overflow Question Titled: Function return value in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286164/function-return-value-in-powershell/68942633#68942633)

The follow code was the answer provided by [user:8291353](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8291353/3lvinaz) or **3lvinaz**:

```
function Return-Url
{
   param([string] $url)

   . {
       $rs = $url.ToString();
       return
   } | Out-Null
   
   return $rs
}

$result = Return-Url -url "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286164/function-return-value-in-powershell"

Write-Host $result
Write-Host $result.GetType()
```

My questions:

1. What does the "**.**" (period) do, found before the first "**{**" (curly brace) of the code's function?
2. And if the Function was 'advanced' where would the "**.**" go then?  I tried putting one before the "**{**" in "**process {**" but PowerShell didn't like that.  So if you had the following function structure where would it go?

   ```
    function Verb-Noun {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ()

    begin {

    }

    process {

    }

    end {

    }}
   ```

Take Care and Thank You for your time,

Comment: that dot sourced scriptblock there is nonsense really. you should ignore it.

Comment: The ```.``` is “dot sourcing” the script block - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.4#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing. Script blocks run in a *child* scope which tracks its own execution context - variables, modules, etc. “dot sourcing” runs the scriptblock in the *current* scope instead of creating a new child scope. It has its uses, but it does nothing in the code sample you’ve posted. The way it’s used in your code is… odd - you wouldn’t normally see it used like that in production code.

Answer (score 3):

> What does the `.` (period) do, found before the first `{` (curly brace) of the code's function?

The period, also known as [dot sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#dot-sourcing-operator-), along with the [call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-) are the 2 most commonly used ways invoke que a [scriptblock `{ ... }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.4).

Most notable difference between these 2 is that the `.` runs in the current scope, meaning that anything that happens inside can alter the caller's state, i.e.:

```bash
$var = 'hello'
. { $var = 'world' }
$var # Outputs: world
```

Whereas `&` runs in a child scope:

```bash
$var = 'hello'
& { $var = 'world' }
$var # Outputs: hello
```

> And if the Function was 'advanced' where would the `.` go then? I tried putting one before the `{` in `process {` but PowerShell didn't like that. So if you had the following function structure where would it go?

In the context of your function, it shouldn't go anywhere because it is doing absolutely nothing other than adding overhead, the function might as well be reduced to:

```
function Return-Url {
    param([string] $url)
    
    $url
}
```

Not even `.ToString()` would be needed due to coercion from your `$url` parameter to a `string`.

However if you had a need from invoking or dot sourcing a scriptblock, you could do so in any of the function's methods, and only depends on in which block you want to invoke it.

```
function Return-Url {
    begin {
        . { $foo = 'foo' }
    }
    process {
        . { $bar = 'bar' }
    }
    end {
        . { $baz = 'baz' }

        $foo, $bar, $baz
    }
}

Return-Url
```